# How does optical computing work and deal with nonlinearity?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, hardware

[This article](https://bdtechtalks.com/2019/05/06/lightelligence-optical-ai-hardware-accelerator/) states that:

> One of the algorithms that photonics is very good at implementing is matrix multiplication

But how are parameters stored and updated(in backpropagation)?

One more serious problem is that there are nonlinear operations in neural networks, then how does the photonic neural network deal with activation functions?